# What is the expected number of ice creams that the saloon can still sell until the first customer who wants chocolate has to be dissapointed?

Tags: probability, statistics

An ice saloon sells ice creams with one, two, or three scoops. Customers can choose from ten tastes, but you may also choose for more than one scoop with the same taste. The order of the scoops on the horn is irrelevant, but the number of each taste does matter.

The tray with chololate ice is empty. Assume that each of the 285 different types of ice cream is sold with equal probability. What is the expected number of ice creams that the saloon can still sell until the first customer who wants chocolate has to be dissapointed?

---

**My attempt**

The number of ice creams with chocolate is : $1 \text{ (the case with one scoop) } + 11 \text{ (the case with two scoops) } + (1+9\cdot 9 + 9) \text{ (the case with three scoops) } = 103$.

Since I think that $Y$ = #number of icecreams that can be sold before the first customer wants chocolate is $\sim Geo(\frac{103}{285})$. I highly doubt however whether I calculated the number of possible ice creams with chocolate correctly. Could anyone please check/comment on my approach and/or help me in obtaining the correct solution?

Comment: Case with two scoops and at least one chocolate: There are 10 possibilites, because the second scoop can be any other taste but chocolate, too. Similarly, for three scoops, where at least one of them is chocolate, should be $10^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the number of types with at least one scoop of chocolate is not counted correctly. There are not very many categories, so we can do a cases analysis.

One scoop:  ($1$)

Two scoops: double chocolate ($1$) or chocolate with something else ($9$)

Three scoops: triple chocolate ($1$), double chocolate with something else ($9$), single chocolate and two different flavours ($36$), single chocolate and a doubled flavour ($9$)

**Added:** In the usual introductory probability courses, a geometric random variable measures the number of trials *up to and including* the first success. In that sense, the number $Y$ of ice-creams sold *before* the first request for chocolate is not geometric. But $Y+1$ is. So if you are going to use a canned formula for the expectation of a geometric, you will need to subtract $1$ to get the answer to the ice-cream problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you please elaborate on how you obtained the first to last figure (the $36$  for 'single chocolate and two different flavours')?

Comment: For single chocolate and two different flavours, we **choose** the two flavours from the $9$. This can be done in $\binom{9}{2}$ ways. For single chocolate and a doubled flavour, we **choose** the doubled flavour from the $9$, so this can be done in $\binom{9}{1}$ ways, though that's too fancy, clearly $9$ ways.

Comment: Ah ok, on second thought I figured the second one out as it is indeed obvious once you think about it. Thanks again for your help!